# java tagmaker program (clear scanner and tester class)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**instructions:
write a class called TagMaker that prints out tags. supply methods to (a) set the name (b) set the organization (c) print tag with the name and organization (d) clear the name and organization (e) print a blank tag. then write a TagTester class to test the TagMaker class.**

so i got the code to accept the user input and print out a tag...but i did it without a tester class (i'm scared of those, and it wasn't working when i tried using one. any suggestions there?) and i've tried experimenting with codes that would clear the scanner to print out a blank tag also but it kept messing up the program so i took it out.

this is what i have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.Locale;
//import java.io.*;

public class TagMaker {

 public static void main (String[] args)
{
 Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner( System.in );


 System.out.print("This program will print out a name tag");
 System.out.println("for each delegate.");
 System.out.println("Please enter first name:");
 String first = scannerObject.next();
 System.out.println("Please enter last name:");
 String last = scannerObject.next();
 System.out.println("Please enter organization or affilation:");
 String org = scannerObject.next();


System.out.println("###### " + "Annual Conference" + " ######");
    System.out.println("### NAME: " + first + " " + last + " ###");
    System.out.println("################################");
    System.out.println("### ORGANIZATION:" + org + "###");
    System.out.println("###############################");


    String junk = scannerObject.next();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TagMaker {
private String tagName;
private String organization;

public void setTagName(String tagName){
    this.tagName = tagName;
}

public void setOrganization(String organization){
    this.organization = organization;
}

public void clearTagName(){
    this.tagName = "";
}

public void clearOrganization(){
    this.organization = "";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Tag [Name=" + tagName + "\n Organization="
            + organization + "]";
}


}

class TagTester{

    public static void main(String args[]){
    TagMaker customTag = new TagMaker();                //Creates a new tag
    customTag.setTagName("Custom Name");                //Sets tag name to Custom Name
    customTag.setOrganization("Custom Organization");   //Sets tag organization to Custom organization
    customTag.clearTagName();                           //Clears tag name
    customTag.clearOrganization();                      //Clears organization
    System.out.println(customTag);                      //Prints tag name and organization
}
}
```